# Relation between Information and the number of elements in a discretization of a continuous variable

Tags: discrete-data, information-theory, mutual-information

Imagine that we have a random continuous variable X with an uniform probability between 0 and 1. (It might be a user's rating for example).
We are not given the exact value but Y, the range where the value stands provided that the interval [0,1] is sliced in N smaller intervals with the same size (1/N). In our example of user's satisfaction, it is the number of stars the user can choose to give their rating.

To make the problem very simple (without lack of generality) , we can imagine that $N=2^n$ so $n$ is the number of bits we know in the decimal expression of X.

Intuitively, it is far more important to have the first bit than the 3654st. But, information theory does not follow that intuition as any bit of data is 1 bit of information as its probability is 0.5. That is what we get when we calculate mutual information between Y and X : $I(X,Y)=n$

**I wonder if there exists a kind of heuristic (ideally with a motivation) that would give a weight $w_n$ to the knowledge of each bit of data given its position n**. That would lead to a measure of pseudo-information $Z_n=\sum_{i=1}^nw_i$. It seems a good idea the $Z_n$ does not diverge when n increases. Maybe $w_n=\frac{1}{2^n}$ is a good idea ?

Comment: I think the importance of some bits over the others is due to the fact that your variables live on a structured space (the space of real numbers), with an ordering, and even a metric on it, not any arbitrary space where the bins are not related to each other. So I guess any measure of the importance of the bits should be defined using this metric. For instance, you could say that a bit is very important if when you switch it, the new encoded number is (on average over the possible remaining bits or sth like this) to a far distance (absolute difference) from the initial encoded number ?

Comment: Really not sure about this but you might be interested about the d-tilted information measure, introduced for instance in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.3944.pdf (II.B): it's a measure of information that takes into account a measure of distortion for the problem at hand (for instance, the absolute difference between two numbers)